# Sum of series $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3 3^k}{3^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate the following sum: $$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin^3 3^k}{3^k}$$

Unfortunately I have no idea how to handle with this problem.

Could anyone show it solution?

Comment: You probably have a reason to hope this can be done in closed form (perhaps it was a contest problem, for example). Otherise, I would never think it could be done.  What, may I ask, is your reason for optimism?

Comment: I am not sure is it a contest problem or not, but i found in one of the papers of problem-solving seminars of my university.

Comment: @FelixMarin I believe I've warned you not to run amok introducing personal stylistic quirks to other people's posts. [`\frac` is the proper way to write fractions, not `\over`.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822) Question marks are not to be preceded with a space in English, and it's downright ridiculous to add a period afterwards.

Comment: @RFZ: You didn't sign the right answer (until now) ?

Comment: @Khosrotash, You want likes? :) Oh man this sounds awful :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using 
$$\sin(3a)=3\sin a-4\sin^3a \to \color{red}{\sin^3(a)=\frac14\Big(3\sin a-\sin(3a)\Big)} $$

so
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(3^k)}{3^k}
&=&
\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3\sin(3^k)-\sin(3.3^k)}{3^k}\\
&=&
\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(3^k)}{3^{k-1}}-\frac{\sin(3^{k+1})}{3^{k}}\\
&=&
\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)-f(k+1)\\
&=&\frac14\Big(\frac{\sin3}{3^{1-1}}-\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(3^{n+1})}{3^n}\Big)\\
&=&\frac{\sin(3)}{4}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Pov: You unlocked god level. (+1)

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari: thank you a ton.

Comment: I wonder why your answer didn't get accepted. It is literally the best way to do it.

Answer (score 11):

An overkill. Let $\mathfrak{M}\left(*,s\right)
 $ the Mellin transform. Using the identity $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\lambda_{k}g\left(\mu_{k}x\right),\, s\right)=\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\lambda_{k}}{\mu_{k}^{s}}\mathfrak{M}\left(g\left(x\right),s\right)
 $$ we have $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\sin^{3}\left(3^{k}x\right)}{3^{k}},\, s\right)=\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\left(\frac{1}{3^{s+1}}\right)^{k}\mathfrak{M}\left(\sin^{3}\left(x\right),s\right)
 $$ and since $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sin^{3}\left(x\right),s\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)}{4}\left(3-\frac{1}{3^{s}}\right)
 $$ we have for $\textrm{Re}\left(s\right)>-1
 $ $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\sin^{3}\left(3^{k}x\right)}{3^{k}},\, s\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)}{4}\left(3-\frac{1}{3^{s}}\right)\frac{1}{3^{s+1}-1}=\frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)3^{-s}}{4}
 $$ and so inverting we get $$\underset{k\geq1}{\sum}\frac{\sin^{3}\left(3^{k}x\right)}{3^{k}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{1/2-i\infty}^{1/2+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)3^{-s}}{4}x^{-s}ds
 $$ now taking $x=1$ and shifting the complex line to the left we have, from the residue theorem, that we have to evaluate the residues of $$\textrm{Res}_{s=-2n-1} \frac{\Gamma\left(s\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)3^{-s}}{4}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{4\left(2k+1\right)!3^{-2n-1}}
 $$ hence $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\sin^{3}\left(3^{k}\right)}{3^{k}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}3^{2k+1}=\color{red}{\frac{\sin\left(3\right)}{4}}.$$

Comment: badass $ (+1) $

Answer (score 5):

We can use the following identity (leaving for you to prove)

$$
\sin^3 (3^x) = \frac {1}{4} ( 3 \sin(3^x) - \sin (3^{x+1}) )
$$

That is,

$$
\frac {\sin^3( 3) }{3} =  \frac {1}{4} ( \sin (3) - \frac {1}{3} \sin (3^2) )
$$
$$
\frac {\sin^3( 3^2) }{3^2} =  \frac {1}{4} (\frac {1}{3} \sin (3^2) - \frac {1}{3^2} \sin (3^3) )
$$
$$
\frac {\sin^3( 3^3) }{3^3} =  \frac {1}{4} (\frac {1}{3^3} \sin (3^3) - \frac {1}{3^4} \sin (3^4) )
$$
As you can clearly see, all the middle terms cancel out in the sum and we are only left with the first term. So the sum is $$\frac {\sin (3)} {4} $$.

Comment: +1 Pretty fine. The obvious way.